# Did anyone know to connet data to Dotnetbar Advtree using OLE DB?

Tags: dotnetbar

I want to retrive data to DOTNETBAR ADVTREE using OLEDB connection on VB.NET, but I Can't get the similar tutorials anywhere...

thx...

Regards

Yudistira

Answer (score 0):

Simply use DataSource property to assign your data source to control. Use DisplayMembers property to set comma separated list of fields to display in tree. This is very similar to how most data-binding works in WinForms. Sample project which you can find at My Documents\DotNetBar WinForms Samples\TreeControl also shows this working.